# Is database deleted on clicking "reinstall" button in Wordpress updates?

Tags: database, updates

I have a blog made with WordPress. If I click "Re-install" button present in WordPress updates page, will all the database be dropped and created again? Will my posts be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

No. it does not .
And your post will not be deleted 
 Updates from the wordpress interface regard only the core `FILES`. not the DB.
However, sometimes, between versions, a db upgrade can be made which is mainly reordering or fixing DB. Not deleting entries.

It is at any rate recommended to do a db backup before any upgrade / update.

Answer (score 0):

A Wordpress update will not drop (clear) your DB. You could backup your DB before the update in case there is some problem, but that is not at all likely to happen... having a backup on hand is a good idea anyway.